# Code stopping on =IFERROR(VLOOKUP)

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following line of code in a macro but the code keeps stopping when it reaches it.

```
With Range("L2:L" & ZRow)
    .Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,[WhoDidWhat.xlsx]Who_Did_What!$A:&H,7,0),VLOOKUP(B2,[WhoDidWhat.xlsx]Who_Did_What!$B:$H,6,0)"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

If I put each VLookup in separately they both work apart from returning #NA hence the reason for using Iferror.

Can anyone point out where I might be going wrong or suggest another option?

Comment: There is a closing bracket `)` missing in the end for closing the `=IFERROR(` starting bracket. And a `&` instead of a `$` in `$A:&H`. So this question can be closed due to be off-topic because of  "*typographical error only*".

Comment: Thanks, tried that but it hasn't made any difference.

Comment: I just tested this it works with both changes. I used this formula, so at least the formula is correct and doesn't throw any errors in VBA: `"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,[WhoDidWhat.xlsx]Who_Did_What!$A:$H,7,0),VLOOKUP(B2,[WhoDidWhat.xlsx]Who_Did_What!$B:$H,6,0))"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just think you have a problem with the first VLOOKUP when you are trying to get cells of Who_Did_What.

**Replace** 
`VLOOKUP(A2,[WhoDidWhat.xlsx]Who_Did_What!$A:&H,7,0)`

**by** 
`VLOOKUP(A2,[WhoDidWhat.xlsx]Who_Did_What!$A:$H,7,0)`

(the problem is maybe because of the second "$", you misplaced "&" instead)

***Edit:***

You also forgot a ")".

Clément

Comment: I've removed the £ from the formula and it is now working, Thank You, I never even noticed that.

Comment: I recommend to close this question as off-topic: *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner **unlikely to help future readers**."*